# MysqlConnection string: get Date in (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime

I develop an application in .Net C# that retrieves and insert data in a MySQL database.

To establish the connection I use `MySqlConnection`...

Inside my database, there is several tables each containing multiple date columns in format (`yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm: ss`)

My problem is that when I get columns by SQL request, my dates are in format (`dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`).

I could use the `DateFormat()` to format the columns, but there are a lot of columns date, and the request can change.

I would like to know if there is a way to impose a date format in the string `MyConnection` or something like that.

My string is:

```
string MyConnection = "datasource=192.168.0.1;port=3306;username=" + this.textBoxLogin.Text.ToString().Trim() +
                ";password=" + this.textBoxPassword.Text.ToString().Trim() + ";AllowZeroDateTime=True;TreatTinyAsBoolean=False;";
```

Queries + Getting Data + insertion in `.xls` file:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
conn.Open();

dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * From table;", conn);
MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

////get data
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

////insert in .xls File
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
CreateWorkbook("test\\Export.xls", dataSet);
```

Date format in Database: `2015/02/25 13:28:25`

Date format in my `.xls` file: `25/02/2015 13:28:25`

Comment: You just show your connection string. Show your queries and data types of your columns. And these formats are just for representation of them. If you keep them as `DATE` they _can't_ have any format.

Comment: Thaks for the fast answer. i have add more information

Comment: Set the culture info of `dataSet.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;` as per (the last part of) my answer.

Comment: Sorry little mistake in my question about Date format in Data base and Date format in my .xls File . i mixe them.
i correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database stores the data in a `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp` data type, .NET will put that in a `DateTime` struct. This is perfectly fine since this is just the structure of the data, not the visual representation of it.

If you want to change the default date format of your program (which fixes it once for all for all dates), you can set the `CurrentCulture` to a culture that you require:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

If you just need to set the date format, you can set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: instead of `dataSet.Locale =System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;`
i put 'dataSet.Locale = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");'
or like you say in your responce but it does not fix the problem.
may be I did something wrong I verified

Comment: `en-US` is just a sample culture. Set it to the one you need, having the date format you require. Or set the `DateTimeFormat` property of your current culture.

Comment: Thanks a lot i have solve it with System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP")